# SQL query with multiple tables, possible to apply group by only to count(*)?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to list bookjobs info for jobtype 'N' and having publishers creditcode of 'C'. Then, add a count of the total number of po's (purchase orders- from table pos) for each row of the previous queries' output. Can you use group by to apply only to that count and not to the rest of the query? Do i have to use a join? My attempts thus far have been unsuccessful.
These are the tables i am working with:

```
bookjobs:
+--------+---------+----------+
| job_id | cust_id | jobtype  |
+--------+---------+----------+
publishers:
+---------+------------+------------+
| cust_id | name       | creditcode |
+---------+------------+------------+
pos:
+--------+-------+------------+-----------+
| job_id | po_id | po_date    | vendor_id |
+--------+-------+------------+-----------+
```

This is what i came up with, although it is wrong (count is not grouped to job_id):

```
select b.*, (select count(*) from pos o) as count 
from bookjobs b, publishers p, pos o 
where b.cust_id=p.cust_id 
   and b.job_id=o.job_id 
   and b.jobtype='N' 
   and p.creditcode='C';
```

I believe i need to have the count grouped by job_id, but not the rest of the query. Is this possible or do i need to use a join? I tried a few joins but couldn't get anything to work. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sql

```
select b.*, (select count(*) from pos where job_id=o.job_id) as count 
from bookjobs b, publishers p, pos o 
where b.cust_id=p.cust_id 
   and b.job_id=o.job_id 
   and b.jobtype='N' 
   and p.creditcode='C';
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you describe, I would assume that your original query would return duplicate rows.  You can fix this by pre-aggregating the `pos` table and then joining it in:

```
select b.*, o.cnt
from bookjobs b join
     publishers p
     on b.cust_id = p.cust_id join
     (select job_id, count(*) as cnt
      from pos o 
      group by job_id
     ) o
     on b.job_id = o.job_id
where b.jobtype = 'N' and p.creditcode = 'C';
```